# Strategy to sync 2 Microsoft SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-synchronization

I've gotta admit that I'm a Microsoft .NET developer, and I'm not an expert in SQL Server. 
I have developed a Windows app, with data stored in my local SQL Server (Express version). I recently purchase a shared hosting service, including a SQL Server. I thought about backing up my local data to remote server: about 5-6 tables from my local SQL Server to remote server, and 1-2 tables from remote to local

What's the best way to do this? DB size is limited to about 5-10MB. The structure of 2 DBs are different, synced tables have same structures. Is there an automatic script I can run from SQL Server Express to do this task every 15 minutes or so?

Answer (score 1):

For initial publishing I’d just go with restoring a backup in the hosting environment. For further synchronization you can try some of the 3rd party tools such as [ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) or [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) or basically any other tool in this category…